# How do I return a map-values iterator from a class function?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, return, c++20

The following code compiles fine in C++ 20 (e.g., using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) when using `auto` as a return type of `get_map_values_iterator()`. However, I want to split this class into implementation and header files, and it seems I cannot use `auto` as a return type in a class header (which I think I understand why).

So I have tried spelling out the type name of the return value with the help of my IDE, and I came up with

`std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<int, std::string>>, 1>::_Iterator<true>`

However, `_Iterator` seems to be private, and I am getting errors such as

> main.cpp:6:83: error: ‘template struct std::ranges::elements_view > >, 1>::_Iterator’ is private within this context

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    // auto // this works
    std::ranges::elements_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::map<int, std::string>>, 1>::_Iterator<true> // this fails
    get_map_values_iterator() {
        auto values = std::ranges::views::values(my_map);
        auto iterator = values.begin();
        return iterator;
    }
private:
    std::map<int, std::string> my_map;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.get_map_values_iterator();
    return 0;
}
```

I have also figured out that I can implement this function (with `auto`) in the header file, which is an OKish workaround. But to do it properly, how can I define a class function in an implementation file that returns `iterator`?

Comment: Since lifetime of `my_map` ends with function scope any iterator pointing to it is invalid. So you have undefined behavior. Problem is not "return" but lifetime of container.

Comment: Can we get a better/more complete example?  As is the function will lead you to UB as you are returning a iterator to a container that no longer exists.  You should be able to use the trailing return type syntax but it would help to have more context to figure out how that would look.

Comment: This question suffers from [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem): "fix my solution" instead "how to solve this particular problem".

Comment: Also can't reproduce problem in way it is described: https://godbolt.org/z/qEPYrfbrY

Comment: @MarekR I want to embed this in a class, so `my_map` would be a class member.

Comment: @MarekR the code stop compiling when you replace `auto` by the actual type. Fixed the code example for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have wrapped the example in a class to solve the life-time issues. (I don't think the *compiler* cares about life-time, but well.)

Comment: @bers It was more a name scope issue.  I've added an answer that leverages that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `begin()` is not the only iterator that needs to be returned, thus trailing return type `-> decltype()` is overwording. You can use a deduced iterator type as a user type:

```
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>

class A {
  private:
    std::map<int, std::string> my_map;

  public:
    using my_iterator = decltype(std::ranges::views::values(my_map).begin());

    my_iterator get_map_begin();
    my_iterator get_map_end();
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.get_map_begin();
    a.get_map_end();
    return 0;
}

A::my_iterator A::get_map_begin() {
    const auto& values = std::ranges::views::values(my_map);
    auto iterator = values.begin();
    return iterator;
}

A::my_iterator A::get_map_end() {
    const auto& values = std::ranges::views::values(my_map);
    auto iterator = values.end();
    return iterator;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the trailing return type syntax to "use" the class member to determine the return type of the function.  That looks like:

```
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>

class A {
private:
    std::map<int, std::string> my_map;
public:
    auto get_map_values_iterator() -> decltype(std::ranges::views::values(my_map).begin());

};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.get_map_values_iterator();
}

auto A::get_map_values_iterator() -> decltype(std::ranges::views::values(my_map).begin())  {
    return std::ranges::views::values(my_map).begin();
}
```

This does requires that `my_map` is visible before you use it in the trailing return type for the function declaration.